# Reference request: Generalization of power iteration recurrence $B_{k+1}=\frac{AB_{k}}{||AB_{k}||}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations

> What is it known of the behavior of the recurrence $$B_{k+1}=\frac{AB_{k}}{||AB_{k}||}$$ ,i.e, the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) recurrence when the vector is replaced by a matrix (if $A$ has dimensions $n\times n$, consider $B$ of dimensions $n\times d, d \geq 2$) and in the denominator we have a matrix norm?

When $d=2$, it can be seen as a (discrete) polygonal flow. I've tried some simulations and the points tend to converge in a line or diverge depending of the eigenvalues of $A$. Note that the recurrence is a bit different from what is employed in the generalized eigenvalue problem: $x_{k+1}= B^{-1}Ax_{k}$, where $x_{k}$ is a vector.

Comment: Wouldn't this be equivalent to just applying the standard power iteration on each of the $d$ columns of $B$ with modified scaling? I suspect that you will end up with a matrix where each column is very close to the domainant eigenvector of $A$ most of the time.